# How to pass state variable values to non child components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a function to read data from firebase and i want to pass the retrieved data to other non child components... following is my code....

```
 readdata() {
    var ref = fire.database().ref('Employers');
     ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        var joblist = []; 
          snapshot.forEach((child)=> {
             child.forEach((child1)=>{
             joblist.push(child1.val())
              let newState = [];
                 for (let item in joblist) {
                 newState.push({
                     id: item,
                     title: joblist[item].Title,
                     description: joblist[item].Description,
                     location: joblist[item].Location,
                     rateperhour: joblist[item].RatePerHour,
                 });
                 this.setState({
                    slidercontents: newState
                }); 
            }  
        }) 
        this.setState({empname : child.key})  
        });  

    });

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the result in the global state using redux or the context api?

Comment: no im new to react... can you tell me how?

Comment: Read up official Redux documentation (it is a popular package to use with React)

Comment: @RakeshRajan: If you never heard of `redux` then why are you tagging `react-redux` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to parent component, you can pass function in props and then send data in argument. e.g.

```
<MyComponent
  sendData={(data) => {console.log(data)}}
/>
// in component
this.props.sendData(data)
```

Other ways are using react context api [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b) or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in localStorage then get it back in your nonchild component from your local storage. But using redux would be the best option here.